# Динамический массив и его указатель для функций ввода и вывода

Tags: c, файлы, malloc

Здравствуйте: есть две функции (ввода - >>  без обработки вывода на файл) Проблема заключается в следующем. В теле основной программы выделяется a, а указатель на него отдается функциям. Все хорошо, но не до результата, который естественно неверен:

```
A[0]= -842150451 
A[1]= -842150451 
A[2]= -842150451 
A[3]= -842150451 
A[4]= -842150451
```

(вероятно сами значения - это указатель на массив динамический). Пытаюсь засунуть выделение динамического массива в функцию ввода (ниже по коду - `input_arrayA_from_file(a,n)`, получаются интеррапты - никак не могу додуматься как передать указатель на массив, чтоб в итоге все получилось.

```
printf("Введите размерность массива A: ");
scanf("%i", &n);
a = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
// вызываемый прототип функции ввода
printf("-------Введите данные с файла test.txt, расположенного непосредственно в папке с программой-------");


input_arrayA_from_file(a,n);
output_arrayA_file(a,n);


void input_arrayA_from_file(int *a,int size)
{

    FILE * f1;

    f1 = fopen("test.txt", "r");

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        fscanf(f1, " %d", a + i);
    }
    fclose(f1);

}


void output_arrayA_file(int *a,int size)
{

    FILE * f1;
    f1 = fopen("test.txt", "w");
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        fprintf(f1, "A[%d]= %d ", i, a[i]);
    }
    fclose(f1);

}
```

Comment: Я правильно вас понял, что в файл вы пишете строки типа `A[1] = 5`, а читать из него пытаетесь просто числа?...

Comment: Нет. Это уже результат работы Функции вывода. Могу отформатировать под лаконичный форматированный вывод, ситуация не изменится. Будто затирает..

Comment: Ну понятно, что при записи затирает содержимое файла. Вы смотрели внутрь "test.txt" **перед** запуском программы?

Comment: Да. Вводил значения беспрерывным потоком.

Comment: Что "да"? Смотрели? Что в нем записано?

Comment: После работы программы в любом случае: то, что я показал. Если до компиляции - то, файл пуст (он создаётся один раз, я ввожу туда данные, п на выводе...

Comment: Я бы мог решить вопрос путем рандомного заполнения файла с последующим считыванием, но это воспрещается.

Comment: У меня (linux, gcc 7.4.0) работает, результат -- `A[0]= 123 A[1]= 124 A[2]= 125 A[3]= 126`. На всякий случай, приведите полный код main вместе с #includ-ами

Comment: Если файл пуст - то что вы пытаетесь из него прочесть?!! 8-/ Естественно, в вашем массиве мусор. Попробуйте тут - `fscanf(f1, " %d", a + i);` - смотреть, что возвращает этот вызов. Если `EOF` - то вы просто ничего не читаете!\

Comment: @avp Откуда у вас берутся эти значения? я не вижу ничего, кроме чтения из файла - который, как выясняется, пуст...

Comment: @Harry, естественно, набил файл из 4-х чисел

Comment: @avp Тогда понятно... А вот ТС этого почему-то не делал... :)

Comment: Делал..! К сожалению, ещё раз воспользоваться программой смогу только утром.  Интересно, конечно, получается.

Comment: @tilandiya, [`fscanf(f1, " %d", a + i)`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf)  при успешном вводе вернет 1. Советую проверять ввода результат каждого числа

Comment: Спасибо огромное!